# I am trying to solve nonlinear Schrödinger equation with dipolar interaction

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear, fourier-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to solve numerically Equation number (29) with the help of Eq.(32) and (34) from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03283.pdf.

for

```
Subscript[N, at]=10000,a=100*Subscript[a, B]
Subscript[a, dd]=132.7*Subscript[a, B],Subscript[a, B]=5.29*10^-5,
Subscript[d, ρ]=1,λ=0.5
```

[image]

```
Subscript[a, dd] = 132.7*5.29*10^-5;
        a0 = 100*5.29*10^-5;
λ = 0.5;
n = 20;
xg = N[Range[n]]/(n + 1);
Subscript[d, ρ] = 1;
Nat = 10000
Subscript[h, 1 D] = 
 Interpolation[
  Table[{Subscript[k, z], 
    NIntegrate[
     1/(2 π (Subscript[d, ρ])^2) ((
        3 ((Subscript[k, z] Subscript[d, ρ])/Sqrt[2])^2)/(
        u + ((Subscript[k, z] Subscript[d, ρ])/Sqrt[2])^2) - 
        1) Exp[-u], {u, 0, ∞}]}, {Subscript[k, z], 1, 2, 
    0.005}]]
uxx[u_?VectorQ] := Module[{n = Length[u]},
  FourierDST[Subscript[h, 1 D] FourierDST[u, 1], 1]]
usol = NDSolveValue[{I D[ϕ[z, t], 
      t] = -1/2 D[ϕ[z, t], z, z] + 
      1/2 λ^2 z^2 ϕ[z, t] + (
       2 a Nat)/(Subscript[d, ρ])^2 Abs[ϕ[z, t]]^2 ϕ[z,
         t] + 3 Subscript[a, dd]  Subscript[N, at]
        uxx[ϕ[z, t]] ϕ[z, t] == 0, ϕ[z, 0] == 
    E^(-λ (xg)^2/2)*(λ/Pi)^(1/4), ϕ[n, 
     t] = ϕ[-n, t]}, ϕ, {t, 0, 20}, {z, -n, n}]
Plot3D[Abs[usol[z,t]]^2, {t, 0, 1}, {z, -a/1.5, 0}, PlotPoints -> 50,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

This code is able to find the ground state of the equation without the Last Integral Term

```
m = ℏ = 1;
λ = 0.5;
L = 10;
aB = 5.29*10^-5;
a0 = 100*aB;
dρ = 1;
add = 132.7*aB;
Nat = 10000;
nmax = 1000;
Δ = L/(nmax + 1);
zgrid = Range[nmax]*Δ;
W[z_] = λ*z^2/2;
Wgrid = W /@ zgrid;
groundstate[δβ_?NumericQ, κ_?NumericQ, 
   tolerance_: 10^-10] := 
  Module[{Ke, propKin, propPot2, prop, v0, ϕ},
   (* compute the diagonal elements of exp[-δβ*T] *)
   Ke = Exp[-δβ*Range[nmax]^2*(π^2 ℏ^2)/(
       2 m L^2)] // N;
   (* propagate by a full imaginary-time-step with T *)
   propKin[v_] := Normalize[FourierDST[Ke*FourierDST[v, 1], 1]];
   (* propagate by a half imaginary-time-step with V *)
   propPot2[v_] := 
    Normalize[
     Exp[-(δβ/
         2)*(Wgrid + κ*Abs[v]^2/Δ)]*v];
   (* propagate by a full imaginary-time-step by *)
   (* H=T+V using the Trotter approximation *)
   prop[v_] := propPot2[propKin[propPot2[v]]];
   (* random starting point *)
   v0 = Normalize@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], nmax];
   (* propagation to the ground state *)
   ϕ = 
    FixedPoint[prop, v0, 
     SameTest -> Function[{v1, v2}, Norm[v1 - v2] < tolerance]];
   {ϕ}];
With[{κ = (2*a0*Nat)/(dρ)^2, δβ = 10^-4},
 {ϕ} = groundstate[δβ, κ];
 ListLinePlot[
  Join[{{0, 0}}, {zgrid, 
     Abs[ϕ]^2/Δ}\[Transpose], {{L, 0}}], 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

I tried to include the last term in the module but failed. If Anyone can help me with this...

```
h1D = Interpolation[
  Table[{kz, 
    NIntegrate[
     1/(2 π (dρ)^2) ((3 ((kz dρ)/Sqrt[2])^2)/(
        u + ((kz dρ)/Sqrt[2])^2) - 1) Exp[-u], {u, 
      0, ∞}]}, {kz, 1, 2, 0.005}]]
FourierDST[h1D FourierDST[v, 1], 1]]
```

Comment: You may get helpful responses if you share what you have already tried.

Comment: Get familiar with the Mathematica solvers `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue`.  Start small.  Review the examples.  Type NDSolve, hover over it, press the "I" and work through the examples.  Do simple ones first, take some time, then attempt to code yours.  Cut and paste your code for others to review.

Comment: Do you need Mathematica code for this model?  Please, note, that Fortran and CUDA version have been upload  on http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/summaries/AEWL_v1_0.html

Comment: @AlexTrounev Resected sir, I have checked that already but I am eager to solve in MATHEMATICA using split-step Crank-Nicolson Method.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am unable to add the last integral term in the equation. Looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `GaussianQuadratureWeights[]` to compute integrals as in Fortran code in the paper cited. On the first step we define initial data as follows

```
Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

np = 81; g = GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, -L, L]; points = 
 g[[All, 1]];
weights = g[[All, 2]];

sol[0][z_, t_] := E^(-\[Lambda] (z)^2/2)*(\[Lambda]/Pi)^(1/4);
a0 = 5.29*10^-5;
a = 113 a0; dp = 1; add = 
 132.7*5.29*10^-5; Nat = 100; L = 10; \[Lambda] = 0.5; dt = 
 1/100; nt = 600; T = Table[i dt, {i, 0, 1001}];

h1[x_?NumericQ] := 
  1/(2 Pi dp^2) NIntegrate[
    Exp[-u] (3 x^2/(u + x^2) - 1), {u, 0, Infinity}];
h1D = Table[h1[x dp/Sqrt[2]], {x, points}];

nk[0] = Table[
   Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[
      I points[[j]] points[[i]]] Abs[sol[0][points[[i]], 0]]^2, {i, 
     Length[g]}], {j, Length[g]}];
intn[0] = 
  2/3 Table[{points[[j]], 
     Re[Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[-I points[[j]] points[[i]]] h1D[[
         i]] nk[0][[i]], {i, Length[g]}]]}, {j, Length[g]}];
Vdd[0] = Interpolation[
   Join[{{-L, intn[0][[1, 2]]}}, intn[0], {{L, intn[0][[np, 2]]}}]];
```

Then we organize loop to compute solution on every step. There are two possible solutions. To compute nonstationary state we use real time computation as follows

```
Do[sol[s] = 
   NDSolveValue[{-I D[\[Phi][z, t], t] - 1/2 D[\[Phi][z, t], z, z] + 
        1/2 \[Lambda]^2 z^2 \[Phi][z, 
          t] + (2 a Nat)/(dp)^2 Abs[\[Phi][z, t]]^2 \[Phi][z, t] + 
        3 add Nat Vdd[s - 1][z] \[Phi][z, t] == 0, \[Phi][z, T[[s]]] ==
        sol[s - 1][z, T[[s]]], \[Phi][L, t] == 0, \[Phi][-L, t] == 
       0}, \[Phi], {t, T[[s]], T[[s + 1]]}, {z, -L, L}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> np, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}] // Quiet; 
  nk[s] = Table[
    Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[
       I points[[j]] points[[i]]] Abs[
        sol[s][points[[i]], T[[s + 1]]]]^2, {i, Length[g]}], {j, 
     Length[g]}];
  intn[s] = 
   2/3 Table[{points[[j]], 
      Re[Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[-I points[[j]] points[[i]]] h1D[[
          i]] nk[s][[i]], {i, Length[g]}]]}, {j, Length[g]}];
  Vdd[s] = 
   Interpolation[
    Join[{{-L, intn[s][[1, 2]]}}, 
     intn[s], {{L, intn[s][[np, 2]]}}]];, {s, 1, 
   nt}]
```

Visualization of the integral term and numerical solution

```
Table[Plot[Vdd[s][z], {z, -L, L}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> 1. dt s], {s, 0, nt,30}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

```
Table[Plot[Abs[sol[s][z, T[[s + 1]]]], {z, -L, L}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> 1. dt s, PlotRange -> All], {s, 0, nt, 30}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To compute  rms size $<z>$ we use

```
rms = Table[{s, 
   Re[NIntegrate[
      z^2 sol[s][z, T[[s + 1]]] Conjugate[
        sol[s][z, T[[s + 1]]]], {z, -L, L}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 5]]^.5}, {s, 1, nt}]
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[rms]
```

[image: Figure 3]

This is not stationary state nevertheless for about one period we have

```
meanr = 
 Mean[Take[rms], 328]] // Last

(*Out[]= 0.798857*)
```

In the Table 1 this value is about 0.7939 (variational method) or 0.7937 (imaginary time method).To compute ground state we use imaginary time method

```
Do[sol1[s] = 
   NDSolveValue[{ 
      D[\[Phi][z, t], t] - 1/2 D[\[Phi][z, t], z, z] + 
        1/2 \[Lambda]^2 z^2 \[Phi][z, 
          t] + (2 a Nat)/(dp)^2 Abs[\[Phi][z, t]]^2 \[Phi][z, t] + 
        3 add Nat Vdd[s - 1][z] \[Phi][z, t] == 0, \[Phi][z, T[[s]]] ==
        sol[s - 1][z, T[[s]]], \[Phi][L, t] == 0, \[Phi][-L, t] == 
       0}, \[Phi], {t, T[[s]], T[[s + 1]]}, {z, -L, L}, 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MinPoints" -> 40, "MaxPoints" -> np, 
         "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}] // Quiet; 
  nk[s] = Table[
    Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[
       I points[[j]] points[[i]]] Abs[
        sol[s][points[[i]], T[[s + 1]]]]^2, {i, Length[g]}], {j, 
     Length[g]}];
  intn[s] = 
   2/3 Table[{points[[j]], 
      Re[Sum[weights[[i]] Exp[-I points[[j]] points[[i]]] h1D[[
          i]] nk[s][[i]], {i, Length[g]}]]}, {j, Length[g]}];
  Vdd[s] = 
   Interpolation[
    Join[{{-L, intn[s][[1, 2]]}}, 
     intn[s], {{L, intn[s][[np, 2]]}}]];, {s, 1, 
   nt}]
```

To compute  rms size $<z>$ we use

```
rmsg = Table[{s, 
   Re[NIntegrate[
      z^2 sol1[s][z, T[[s + 1]]] Conjugate[
        sol1[s][z, T[[s + 1]]]], {z, -L, L}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 5]]^.5}, {s, 1, nt}]
```

Mean value in one period is about

```
Mean[Take[rmsg, 328]] // Last

Out[]= 0.791021
```

Comment: @AexTrounev Thanks for the solution and giving a great deal of importance to my problem. I like to ask how can I get stationary or ground state solution from this as I need them to calculate Energy and chemical potential. Also dynamical evaluation of the density wave. If you can recommend me advance tutorial or books in MATHEMATICA so that I can deal with typical nonlinear equation or coupled nonlinear equations. I already studied some of your previous solutions. They are helping me immensely.

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick response and also for the solutions. @AlexTrounev